# Can we use the expression "trash somebody" to mean "to ruin somebody"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, idioms, american-english

I know that we can use the expression "trash somebody" to mean "to criticize somebody severely" in American English. My question is, can we also use the same phrase to mean "to ruin somebody"? I am asking this because I know that "trash something" means "to ruin something" like in this example sentence in the Macmillan Dictionary: "The previous tenants completely trashed the flat." So I wonder if we can use "trash" with the same meaning when we talk about ruining a person too whether mentally or physically.

Some examples  just for you to understand what I mean better:

1. Let's say somebody thinks there are injustices against males in his country, can they say, "Men are trashed in my country", to mean "Men are ruined in my country"?
2. Let's say somebody had bad classmates and he was bullied in high school. Can he say, "I got trashed by my class/classmates in high school" to mean "I got ruined by class/classmates in high school"?
3. Let's say Mike Tyson physically ruined his opponent, can we say, "Mike Tyson trashed his opponent in his last match."

Comment: You can say whatever you like. Whether your audience will understand your intended meaning is another matter as none of your examples is idiomatic.

Comment: You're much more likely to hear *Mike Tyson **thrashed** his opponent in his last match*, but ***trashed*** is at least "acceptable" in colloquial spoken contexts (note that it's very "slangy"  though, with both of the senses "severely criticized" AND "convincingly beaten").

Comment: (The metaphoric sense of "converted to trash / garbage" or "made worthless" works equally well for both senses.)

Comment: Be cognizant of the usage "he was trashed" meaning "he was exceedingly drunk".

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica - you're likely confusing "thrashed" and "trashed" - although "ruined" isn't quite the the same - it's more stative.  You'd aalmost lways say who or what transitively did the "thrashing", but if a thing is "ruined", it's can stand as simply a state - "It's ruined."   It also implies a beating or physical damage, when used directly.   Consider:  "debased", "destroyed", "wrecked", "broken", or "damaged" instead.

Comment: to trash someone's **reputation***, please....even when the word reputation is not there, that is what it actually means.